# How do I write a Serde Visitor to convert an array of arrays of strings to a Vec<Vec<f64>>?

Tags: json, serialization, rust, serde

I need to deserialize a JSON into a struct that has a `Vec<Vec<f64>>` field. The JSON has strings for numbers so I need a custom deserializer to convert the strings to `f64` during the deserialization.

A sample JSON that I'd like to deserialize:

```
{
  "values": [["2", "1.4"], ["8.32", "1.5"]]
}
```

My struct is this:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Payload {
    #[serde(default, deserialize_with = "from_array_of_arrays_of_strs")]
    values: Vec<Vec<f64>>,
}
```

I saw you could probably do this with visitors [in the examples of Serde](https://serde.rs/stream-array.html), so I've implemented this visitor:

```
fn from_array_of_arrays_of_strs<'de, T, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<Vec<f64>>, D::Error>
where
    T: Deserialize<'de>,
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    struct F64Visitor(PhantomData<fn() -> Vec<Vec<f64>>>);

    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for F64Visitor {
        type Value = Vec<Vec<f64>>;

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("a nonempty sequence of numbers")
        }

        #[inline]
        fn visit_str<E>(self, value: &str) -> Result<f64, E>
        where
            E: serde::de::Error,
        {
            self.visit_string(String::from(value))
        }

        #[inline]
        fn visit_string<E>(self, value: String) -> Result<f64, E> {
            Ok(value.parse::<f64>().unwrap())
        }

        #[inline]
        fn visit_seq<V, T>(self, mut visitor: V) -> Result<Vec<T>, V::Error>
        where
            V: SeqAccess<'de>,
        {
            let mut vec = Vec::new();

            while let Some(elem) = try!(visitor.next_element()) {
                vec.push(elem);
            }

            Ok(vec)
        }
    }

    let visitor = F64Visitor(PhantomData);
    deserializer.deserialize_seq(visitor)
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=90d5e80118c9a7e799fcdaba3704bb02&version=stable)

The compiler complains that `visit_str` and `visit_string` have an incompatible type for the trait:

```
error[E0053]: method `visit_str` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/main.rs:32:9
   |
32 | /         fn visit_str<E>(self, value: &str) -> Result<f64, E>
33 | |             where
34 | |             E: serde::de::Error,
35 | |         {
36 | |             self.visit_string(String::from(value))
37 | |         }
   | |_________^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found f64
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(from_array_of_arrays_of_strs::F64Visitor, &str) -> std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<f64>>, E>`
              found type `fn(from_array_of_arrays_of_strs::F64Visitor, &str) -> std::result::Result<f64, E>`

error[E0053]: method `visit_string` has an incompatible type for trait
  --> src/main.rs:40:9
   |
40 | /         fn visit_string<E>(self, value: String) -> Result<f64, E> {
41 | |             Ok(value.parse::<f64>().unwrap())
42 | |         }
   | |_________^ expected struct `std::vec::Vec`, found f64
   |
   = note: expected type `fn(from_array_of_arrays_of_strs::F64Visitor, std::string::String) -> std::result::Result<std::vec::Vec<std::vec::Vec<f64>>, E>`
              found type `fn(from_array_of_arrays_of_strs::F64Visitor, std::string::String) -> std::result::Result<f64, E>`

error[E0049]: method `visit_seq` has 2 type parameters but its trait declaration has 1 type parameter
  --> src/main.rs:45:21
   |
45 |         fn visit_seq<V, T>(self, mut visitor: V) -> Result<Vec<T>, V::Error>
   |                     ^^^^^^ found 2 type parameters, expected 1
```

I think I don't have the correct understanding of how visitors work. Can I have only one visitor for deserializing the array of arrays of strings, or do I need one visitor for deserializing the arrays and one visitor for deserializing the strings to `f64`?

I've read:

- [How to transform fields before deserialization using serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753955/how-to-transform-fields-before-deserialization-using-serde)
- [Is there is a simpler way to convert a type upon deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44836327/is-there-is-a-simpler-way-to-convert-a-type-upon-deserialization)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As already described in [How to transform fields before deserialization using serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46753955/155423), the easiest solution is to introduce a *newtype* for your string-as-a-floating-point-value. You can then implement `Deserialize` for that, leveraging existing implementations of `Deserialize` and string parsing:

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Error, Unexpected};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Payload {
    #[serde(default)]
    values: Vec<Vec<Value>>,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Value(f64);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Value {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Value, D::Error>
        where D: Deserializer<'de>
    {
        let s: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        s.parse()
            .map(Value)
            .map_err(|_| D::Error::invalid_value(Unexpected::Str(s), &"a floating point number as a string"))
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"
{
  "values": [["2", "1.4"], ["8.32", "1.5"]]
}
"#;

    let out: Payload = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", out);
}
```

I prefer this solution because in many cases I want that new type to play a role in my system.

---

If you really, truly need to deserialize once and to exactly a `Vec<Vec<f64>>`, you have to implement two visitors. One will deserialize the outer `Vec`, one will deserialize the inner `Vec`. We will reuse the previous `Value` newtype, but the inner visitor will strip it away. The outer visitor will do the same thing for a newtype around the inner visitor:

```
extern crate serde;
#[macro_use]
extern crate serde_derive;
extern crate serde_json;

use serde::de::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Error, SeqAccess, Unexpected, Visitor};
use std::fmt;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct Payload {
    #[serde(default, deserialize_with = "from_array_of_arrays_of_strs")]
    values: Vec<Vec<f64>>,
}

fn from_array_of_arrays_of_strs<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<Vec<f64>>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    struct OuterVisitor;

    impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for OuterVisitor {
        type Value = Vec<Vec<f64>>;

        fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
            formatter.write_str("a nonempty sequence of a sequence of numbers")
        }

        #[inline]
        fn visit_seq<V>(self, mut visitor: V) -> Result<Self::Value, V::Error>
        where
            V: SeqAccess<'de>,
        {
            let mut vec = Vec::new();

            while let Some(Inner(elem)) = try!(visitor.next_element()) {
                vec.push(elem);
            }

            Ok(vec)
        }
    }

    deserializer.deserialize_seq(OuterVisitor)
}

struct Inner(Vec<f64>);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Inner {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Inner, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        struct InnerVisitor;

        impl<'de> Visitor<'de> for InnerVisitor {
            type Value = Inner;

            fn expecting(&self, formatter: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
                formatter.write_str("a nonempty sequence of numbers")
            }

            #[inline]
            fn visit_seq<V>(self, mut visitor: V) -> Result<Inner, V::Error>
            where
                V: SeqAccess<'de>,
            {
                let mut vec = Vec::new();

                while let Some(Value(elem)) = try!(visitor.next_element()) {
                    vec.push(elem);
                }

                Ok(Inner(vec))
            }
        }

        deserializer.deserialize_seq(InnerVisitor)
    }
}

struct Value(f64);

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Value {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Value, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let s: &str = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        s.parse().map(Value).map_err(|_| {
            D::Error::invalid_value(Unexpected::Str(s), &"a floating point number as a string")
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let input = r#"
{
  "values": [["2", "1.4"], ["8.32", "1.5"]]
}
"#;

    let out: Payload = serde_json::from_str(input).unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", out);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Parsing JSON files with strings instead of numbers is also possible without writing a visitor yourself.

```rust
use serde_with::{serde_as, DisplayFromStr};

#[serde_as]
#[derive(Debug, serde::Deserialize)]
struct Payload {
    #[serde_as(as = "Vec<Vec<DisplayFromStr>>")]
    #[serde(default)]
    values: Vec<Vec<f64>>,
}

let j = serde_json::json!({
  "values": [["2", "1.4"], ["8.32", "1.5"]]
});

let p: Payload = serde_json::from_value(j)?;
assert_eq!(p.values, vec![vec![2.0, 1.4], vec![8.32, 1.5]]);
```

The annotation means that we have a `Vec` inside a `Vec` and the innermost elements should be deserialized using `FromStr` and serialized using `Display`. The annotation is supports any type with `Display` and `FromStr` implementations, so it can also be used on `u64` or on `Url` types.

Comment: this is much more concise than the other answer. Is this expected to be as performant as the previous answer?

Comment: The performance should be pretty identical to the accepted answer. One advantage of this solution is that it avoids deserializing `&str`, which is problematic in a couple of cases. You also get the serialization for free.