# Deserialize a Vec<Foobar<T>> as Vec<T> directly when Foobar has exactly one field

Tags: rust, serde

I'm given a data-format that includes a sequence of objects with exactly one named field `value` each. Can I remove this layer of indirection while deserializing?

When deserializing, the natural representation would be

```
/// Each record has it's own `{ value: ... }` object
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct Foobar<T> {
    value: T,
}

/// The naive representation, via `Foobar`...
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct FoobarContainer {
    values: Vec<Foobar<T>>,
}
```

While `Foobar` adds no extra cost beyond `T`, I'd like to remove this layer of indirection at the type-level:

```
#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
struct FoobarContainer {
    values: Vec<T>,
}
```

Can `Foobar` be removed from `FoobarContainer`, while still using it using deserialization?

Comment: @shepmaster, the problem comes with `Vec<...>`, so I need/want to delegate to the `Vec`-deserializer. `deserialize_with="Vec<Foobar<T>>"` is not legal syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the general case, there's no trivial way to make this transformation. For that, review these existing answers:

- [How do I write a Serde Visitor to convert an array of arrays of strings to a Vec<Vec<f64>>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48288988/155423)
- [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753955/how-to-transform-fields-before-deserialization-using-serde)

The first is my normal go-to solution and [looks like this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8d8eb0efbeec42ca056a5ff3d17ce4b9) in this example.

---

However, in your *specific* case, you say:

> objects with exactly one named field value

And you've identified a key requirement:

> While `Foobar` adds no extra cost beyond `T`

This means that you can make `Foobar` have a [*transparent* representation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/type-layout.html#the-transparent-representation) and use **unsafe Rust** to transmute between the types (although [not actually with `mem::transmute`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/64073#issuecomment-533039084)):

```
struct FoobarContainer<T> {
    values: Vec<T>,
}

#[derive(serde::Deserialize)]
#[repr(transparent)]
struct Foobar<T> {
    value: T,
}

impl<'de, T> serde::Deserialize<'de> for FoobarContainer<T>
where
    T: serde::Deserialize<'de>,
{
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: serde::Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let mut v: Vec<Foobar<T>> = serde::Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        // I copied this from Stack Overflow without reading the surrounding
        // text that describes why this is actually safe.
        let values = unsafe {
            let data = v.as_mut_ptr() as *mut T;
            let len = v.len();
            let cap = v.capacity();

            std::mem::forget(v);

            Vec::from_raw_parts(data, len, cap)
        };

        Ok(FoobarContainer { values })
    }
}
```

See also:

- [How do I convert a Vec<T> to a Vec<U> without copying the vector?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48308759/155423)