# How do I transform special values into Option::None when using Serde to deserialize?

Tags: rust, serde

I'm parsing data into:

```
struct Data {
    field1: Option<f32>,
    field2: Option<u64>,
    // more ...
}
```

The problem is that my input data format formats what would be a `None` in Rust as "`n/a`".

How do tell Serde that an `Option<T>` should be `None` for the specific string `n/a`, as opposed to an error? We can assume that this doesn't apply to a `String`.

This isn't the same question as [How to deserialize "NaN" as `nan` with serde_json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54452734/how-to-deserialize-nan-as-nan-with-serde-json) because that's creating an `f32` from a special value whereas my question is creating an `Option<Anything>` from a special value. It's also not [How to transform fields during deserialization using Serde?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753955/how-to-transform-fields-during-deserialization-using-serde) as that still concerns a specific type.

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MCVE]. We can't tell **exactly** what your input looks like, or even if it's JSON or YAML or .... It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write your own deserialization function that handles this case:

```rs
use serde::de::Deserializer;
use serde::Deserialize;

// custom deserializer function
fn deserialize_maybe_nan<'de, D, T: Deserialize<'de>>(
    deserializer: D,
) -> Result<Option<T>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    // we define a local enum type inside of the function
    // because it is untagged, serde will deserialize as the first variant
    // that it can
    #[derive(Deserialize)]
    #[serde(untagged)]
    enum MaybeNA<U> {
        // if it can be parsed as Option<T>, it will be
        Value(Option<U>),
        // otherwise try parsing as a string
        NAString(String),
    }

    // deserialize into local enum
    let value: MaybeNA<T> = Deserialize::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    match value {
        // if parsed as T or None, return that
        MaybeNA::Value(value) => Ok(value),

        // otherwise, if value is string an "n/a", return None
        // (and fail if it is any other string)
        MaybeNA::NAString(string) => {
            if string == "n/a" {
                Ok(None)
            } else {
                Err(serde::de::Error::custom("Unexpected string"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can mark your fields with `#[serde(default, deserialize_with = "deserialize_maybe_nan")]` to use this function instead of the default function:

```
#[derive(Deserialize)]
struct Data {
    #[serde(default, deserialize_with = "deserialize_maybe_nan")]
    field1: Option<f32>,
    #[serde(default, deserialize_with = "deserialize_maybe_nan")]
    field2: Option<u64>,
    // more ...
}
```

[Working playground example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fc17092fa120373a02c1593d39733853)

More information in the documentation:

- [`deserialize_with` serde attribute](https://serde.rs/field-attrs.html#deserialize_with)
- [Untagged enum representation](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged)

Comment: This not only answers my question, but shows how to make a generalized wrapper over serde's existing deserializers.

Comment: @njaard it's exactly what https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753955/how-to-transform-fields-during-deserialization-using-serde say

Comment: This is useful but does not work when used for `String` and the value is a valid integer. Any idea how to proceed here?

Comment: @Manuel What do you mean? When the integer is encoded as a string?